# Confused about my electric dryers heating coil

Tags: electrical, dryer

Okay so like 2 days ago I noticed the electric dryers heating coil has stopped working.. I checked all the bimetal hi limit safety devices that break the circuit when the heating coil is up to temp, and they all had continuity. So I then took the 2 female connectors that attach to the coil, connected each one to my fluke, and as I expected I got 240v's. I then ohmed out the coil itself... i forgot the reading but it wasnt open, and it looked pretty much as I'd expect it to. So I thought maybe it was just a bad connection with all the movement the dryer makes while operating, and reconnected it. Again, nothing. So I then took the coil right out the housing and used a 120v receptacle and alligator clips to test it, instantly it got hot. So at this point I know the coil is fine.. I put it back in the housing and reconnected the two 120v lines and tried again. Same result.. nothing. So being I needed to get some clothes dry in a bad way, I took a length of 14 gauge romex, put a spade connector on one side, and a female connector on the other and soldered it all on. Put the female end on one of the previously 120v lines was, taped up the one I took off, screwed the new wire I made to the neutral, and left the other 120v line that was originally on it as it was. This for some reason works, but now the coil is at half power.. I'm really pretty confused as to why this is happening unless its somehow shorting, but everything keeps testing fine... Can anyone enlighten me here as to what else I can check?? Thank you.

Comment: check everything else. the switch, the wires.

Comment: **Did you recently make any changes to your service panel/breaker box or wiring?**. Certain panel changes will cause this (and much much worse than this).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my answer to this, but no nothing has been changed. Last year i had a circuit breaker weld itself to the panel, so I changed them all when that happened, but as I said that was a while ago, and nothing has been changed since.